# Why does a Raspberry Pi require a key to playback MPEG2 content?

Tags: codec, raspberry-pi, mpeg

[I was reading here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-add-mpeg-2-to-your-raspberry-pi-media-centre/) and the article said that linux distros often use free versions of MPEG2. On my Raspberry Pi, however, I had to purchase a license to achieve playback of some of my files. I never had to do this on my (ubuntu) desktop before. The article I linked to wasn't very clear about the differences between the RPi and my Linux laptop; can anyone expound on the differences between these two?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you *can* decode MPEG2 on a Raspberry Pi *without* the decryption key.  The difference is that **without the key**, you can only use **software decoding**, which makes real-time playback of HD content very challenging considering the Raspberry Pi's hardware (I've noted some dropped frames on mine).

As per the [Raspberry Pi Website](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/), purchasing the license will `enable a single Raspberry Pi to decode MPEG-2 video in hardware`.  The Raspberry Pi is not the most powerful device, and with a single core 700 MHz ARM processor, it might have trouble decoding higher resolution videos.  In this case, you might want to consider purchasing a decoder key to unlock the hardware decoder (which should be capable of decoding even Blu-ray quality MPEG streams).

Note that if you *are* using a Raspberry Pi to play back these videos, some Blu-ray rips (playing back Blu-ray movies directly can be challenging on Linux due to licensing requirements) also use the VC1 codec; there is another applicable hardware decoder you can purchase for that as well - should the software decoder not be fast enough for your needs.